# Difference between CCNode and CCLayer?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

What is the difference between CCNode and CCLayer in Cocos2D?

Answer (score 0):

CCLayer is a CCNode with targeted+standard touch & accelerometer delegated .

CCLayer is inherited by CCNode .

this means it can use all the public properties which CCNode have
rotation,scaleX,scaleY,position,visible.. etc .

with :

CCTargetedTouchDelegate.
ccTouchBegan,ccTouchMoved,ccTouchEnded,ccTouchCancelled

CCStandardTouchDelegate
ccTouchesBegan,ccTouchesMoved,ccTouchesEnded,ccTouchesCancelled

and
UIAccelerometer
accelerometer: